# Twitchbot: Checking if sender is op

Tags: javascript, twitch, pircbot

I am currently working on making a fully custom and free twitchbot for my channel. I am currently in the making of it. I want to make so mods can easily use the kick/ban command with my bot. But I have tried "sender.isOp() == true" but as the 'sender' is a String, I can't check it like that. Any advice or anyone who knows exactly how to do it? All help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with PircBot, but have you looked at TMIJS? It's an entire Javascript framework for creating a twitch bot, and it's very easy to use. https://docs.tmijs.org/v1.1.1/Functions.html

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks! I will check it out. Never heard about TMIJS before.